# gdal.Translate results in a raster which has another extent

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

My input is [this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YGG75vHkGwXb6eximmBZ6SZ1IiXiaM1R/view?usp=sharing)
which gives me an [output file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YuZNNaUl4w4CCIQuD3Chh2Rl489JYWCa/view?usp=sharing) through the code:

```
inputraster=gdal.Open('input_file.tif'),gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
optt=gdal.TranslateOptions(format='PCRaster',bandList=[1],outputSRS='EPSG:4326',outputType=gdalconst.GDT_Int32,metadataOptions='VS_SCALAR')
gdal.Translate('output_file.map',inputraster,options=optt)
```

which has other extent and other resolution.
So, why I get this?

Comment: What are the extents and resolutions of input and output? Ok, found the links, I can check myself.

Comment: Source file has non-square pixels `Pixel Size = (0.002914560266800,0.002632654436743)` and they get converted into squares `Pixel Size = (0.002914560266800,-0.002914560266800)`. I would check first if PCRaster format supports non-square pixels.

Comment: I can see from https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/frmts/pcraster/pcrasterdataset.cpp that `"only the same width and height for cells is supported."`

Comment: Well, I made a file with squared pixel https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IZPqR4d5VnbumqY5ANBui0Us579yhizR/view?usp=sharing 
but the problem is the same https://drive.google.com/file/d/13hVoRoiT-X6IpFdoNP_0bzzMwGulDz2l/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I tried also and I think I had success. Check and report if my test does not feel right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input file has different height and width for pixels

```
Pixel Size = (0.002914560266800,0.002632654436743)
```

The comment in a the source code https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/frmts/pcraster/pcrasterdataset.cpp says that PCRaster does not support that.

> "only the same width and height for cells is supported."

What you did should probably give an error but PCRaster is rather exotic format and probably not thoroughly tested.

You have a few options, maybe the easiest is to convert the source data to have square pixels with gdalwarp

```
gdalwarp input_file.tif input_modified_file.tif
```

and then

```
gdal_translate -of PCRaster input_modified_file.tif output_file3.map
```

Now both files have same values

```
Size is 1259, 1138
Pixel Size = (0.002777186609872,-0.002777186609872)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  42.4506362,  55.4787962) ( 42d27' 2.29"E, 55d28'43.67"N)
Lower Left  (  42.4506362,  52.3183578) ( 42d27' 2.29"E, 52d19' 6.09"N)
Upper Right (  45.9471142,  55.4787962) ( 45d56'49.61"E, 55d28'43.67"N)
Lower Right (  45.9471142,  52.3183578) ( 45d56'49.61"E, 52d19' 6.09"N)
Center      (  44.1988752,  53.8985770) ( 44d11'55.95"E, 53d53'54.88"N)
```

Comment: Although I don't understand the reason why the second tif file with squared pixels doesn't give the proper result, but your idea with processing it with Warp helped. Thanks.